# https.request inside await fetch not working

Tags: javascript, async-await, next.js

I have some code that looks like this in Next JS

```
const resApp = await fetch('/api/club/createsignalapp', {
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: event.target.name.value,
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  method: 'POST',
})

const appResult = await resApp.json()
```

--createsignalapp

```
export default async (req, res) => {
    var mydata
    var createApp = function (data) {
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            Authorization: `Basic APIKKEY`,
        }

        var options = {
            host: 'onesignal.com',
            port: 443,
            path: '/api/v1/apps',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: headers,
        }

        var https = require('https')
        var myreq = https.request(options, function (myres) {
            myres.on('data', function (data) {
                mydata = JSON.parse(data)
                res.statusCode = 200
                res.json({
                    response: {
                        boolean: true,
                        alert: '',
                        message: '',
                    },
                    data: mydata
                })
            })
        })

        myreq.on('error', function (e) {
            console.log(e)
        })

        myreq.write(JSON.stringify(data))
        myreq.end()
    }

    var message = {
        name: req.body.name
    }

    createApp(message)
}
```

This hits the error `API resolved without sending a response for /api/club/createsignalapp, this may result in stalled requests.`
I'm not sure how to do this correctly as i'm getting confused with the awaits and asyncs and requests everywhere.

Happy to hear suggestions.
Thanks

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: is `createsignalapp` server side code? in that code, what is `res`? I think you haven't shown enough of the server side code

Comment: Yeah it's server side in the api folder. I added the function around it if that helps

Comment: It's probably because you've made the function `async` (for absolutely no reason since you never `await` in it) - try `export default (req, res) => { ....` instead - since the way you do it, the function will `resolve` immediately before you've sent any response, some underlying code seems to be aware of this and flagging it as an error

Comment: i.e. you never need to make a function `async` if you never need to `await` directly inside that function